# how to select n-th td of a tr using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I select **nth** `< td >` of a `< tr >` using jquery. Say, I want to select **3rd** `< td >`. I have id for every tr. How can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

using [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) Selector

like

```
$("tr td:nth-child(2)")
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it using `$('#tr td:eq(1)')` as well. Is it correct ?

Comment: I used this with cheerio. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 19):

the [eq api](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) should do this for you

```
$("table td").eq(n)
```

Answer (score 12):

```
$('#id td:nth-child(3)');
```

Like so for the 3rd.

Comment: The nth-child() uses a zero-based index, so the third would be (2).

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/
The index of each child to match, starting with 1....