# Select the 3rd <td> using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table a row and multiple tds in that row, like that:

```
<tr class="first odd">
    <td class="a-center">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td> --> I want this
    <td>...</td> 
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

I am able to get the parent tr of all the tds, but is there a way to get the 3rd td inside the tr only?

The code to get the tr is:

```
jQuery('#shopping-cart-table >  tbody > tr').each(function(index, value) {
    ...
});
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to select n-th td of a tr using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229145/how-to-select-n-th-td-of-a-tr-using-jquery)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `:eq` selector:

```
jQuery('#shopping-cart-table > tbody > tr').each(function(index, value) {
    $('td:eq(2)', this)
});
```

Or:

```
jQuery('#shopping-cart-table tbody').find('td:eq(2)');
```

Comment: @user1856596 That's `$(selector, context)`, `this` refers to the current `tr`.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
$(".first td:nth-child(3)").append("<span>-3rd");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the :eq function in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

```
$('#shopping-cart-table td').eq(2);
```

Comment: .eq(3) will represent the fourth td

Comment: Corrected. P.s, your solution won't work in earlier versions of IE.

Comment: jQuery('#shopping-cart-table > tbody td:eq(2)'); IE must causes conflict with this not mine....I checked

Comment: IE6? Always had the issue with ">" in IE6.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
$("#shopping-cart-table >  tbody > tr td").eq(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer for the title:

```
$("#tableId tr td:nth-child(3)").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the best and easiest code .
You can click  on the button in that row then it will show you the thrid value  .
if this your table :

```
<tr class="first odd">
    <td class="a-center">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td> --> I want this
    <td>...</td> 
    <td>...</td>
    <td><button id='test'><button></td>
</tr>
```

then in javascript bind the button with click event like given below:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').click(function(){
         var thirdData  = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(2)').text();
         alert(thirdData);
    });
});
```

this will solve the problem .

Answer (score 0):

[Sample code, can modify too here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_table)

I think this will solve the problem as you will be able to load any given `<td>` by changing the last Index of this equation `td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];`