# Creating multiple datepickers by passing parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, date, datatable

I am trying to create multiple date pickers using jquery datepicker plugin. I have jquery datatable created along with column filters. For date columns, I need to provide input through datepicker and based on input date, it will filter matching rows. Below is my code:

```
function drawDatePicker(elementId, columnIndex) {
$(elementId).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-y",
    showOn: "button",
    showAnim: 'slideDown',
    showButtonPanel: true ,
    autoSize: true,
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonImage: "images/Calendar.gif",
    onSelect: function(){
        holidayTable.column(columnIndex).search($(this).val()).draw();
    },
    beforeShow: function( input ) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var buttonPane = $( input )
                .datepicker( "widget" )
                .find( ".ui-datepicker-buttonpane" );

            $( "<button>", {
                text: "Clear",
                click: function() {
                //Code to clear date field (text box, read only field etc.)
                    $.datepicker._clearDate( input );
                }
            }).appendTo( buttonPane ).addClass("ui-datepicker-clear ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all");
        }, 1 );
    } 
  });
}

    drawDatePicker('#datepicker',3);
    drawDatePicker('#datepicker1',8);
```

Below is my html table:

```
 <table width="100%" border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing="2" id="holidayTable" class="display">
        <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="dataTableClass" style="width:3%"><input name="selectAll" value="1" id="selectAll" type="checkbox" /></th>
                    <th class="dataTableClass" style="width:5%">Action</th>
                    <th class="dataTableClass" style="width:5%">Sr. No.</th>
                    <th class="dataTableClass" style="width:9%">Holiday Date</th>
                    <th class="dataTableClass" style="width:9%">Holiday Name</th>
                    <th class="dataTableClass" style="width:15%">Holiday Description</th>                       
                    <th class="dataTableClass" style="width:11%">Created / Modified By</th>
                    <th class="dataTableClass" style="width:9%">Created Date</th>
                    <th class="dataTableClass" style="width:3%">Holiday Id</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="filter" id="datepicker" style="width:75%;"/></td>
                    <td>Holiday Name</td>
                    <td>Holiday Description</td>
                    <td>Created / Modified By</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="filter" id="datepicker1" style="width:75%;"/></td>
                    <td></td>
                 </tr> 
        </thead>
     </table>
```

In above snippet, I am trying to pass ids for input elements to which I am attaching datepicker and column index for which I need to create datepicker. In this case I need datepicker for 3rd and 8th columns. But with above code I am not seeing datepicker in webpage and no errors being displayed. Pls suggest.

Comment: In your selector I would suggest trying to find the input within the td rather than the id which datatables might not set. here is an example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957398/select-the-3rd-td-using-jquery

Comment: I have set input element in td with id "datepicker" in html code. Not in jquery code.

Comment: You should show all relevant code to avoid confusion.

Comment: Is all the above JS code inside your document.ready?

Comment: Ah is this code ran after Datatables have been initalised?

Comment: @Sandman No the code was not in Document.ready. But after adding it inside, it is working now. Thank you very much

Comment: No problem Babanna, happy to help. I have included an answer below with an explanation of the importance of including your initialization code within `document.ready` and a link where you can read up on further documentation, if you so wish. Please don't forget to accept & vote if this led to a solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always ensure your control initialization code is within the [`document.ready`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) so that the DOM is ready for the execution of your JavaScript code (i.e. intialization of controls).

Your code would become:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function drawDatePicker(elementId, columnIndex) {
        $(elementId).datepicker({
        ...
        });
    }
    drawDatePicker('#datepicker',3);
    drawDatePicker('#datepicker1',8);
}
```

Or alternatively you can simply use `$(function() {});`

It's a trivial issue, but one that can catch you out time and time again.