# Get single value from entire row using index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am looping through all td's in a single row in the table using the below function.. But I need to get a single cell value from the row

This is my javascript function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%= gvView.ClientID %> input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').children('td').each(function () {
            var signValue = $(this).html(); // here I am getting all td values but I need to get particular value
            alert(signValue);
        });
    });
});
```

How to get single value in same row?

```
<tr>
  <td>adata</td>
  <td>cert</td>
  <td>desc</td>
  <td>virt</td>
  <td>cess</td>
<tr>
```

I need to get fourth td value from the above table

Comment: Do you have sample html I can try out?

Comment: Value of what specifically? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: you have to tell us on which criteria you get one `td` rather than another, a class, id, its position?

Comment: sorry its asp gridview i am looping through the checked rows where i am getting all cells value when i check checkbox in a row

Comment: @Kaddath please let me know if you are not able to understand..

Comment: the jQuery for the position is `eq(index)`, see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229145/how-to-select-n-th-td-of-a-tr-using-jquery). For you this should work `signValue = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(3)').html();` (index starts at 0)

Comment: @Kaddath you made my day please post this as answer i will accept is thanks :)

Comment: not here for points, glad this helped you ;) have a nice coding

Comment: Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

> I need to get fourth td value... from the above table

Use [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
var forthValue = $(this).closest('tr').children('td').eq(3).text();
```

> **index**
>
> An integer indicating the 0-based position of the element.

So, `eq(3)` will give the *4th* `td` value

Answer (score 1):

As per 0 indexing, using `$("tr td:eq(3)")` as selector will let you select the **4th td** & then  using `$("tr td:eq(3)").text()` you can get the value of it.

Comment: This will always return the fourth cell in the whole table...not row specific instances

Comment: My answer is to give a logic of selecting. Same is mentioned in other answers too. It's 0 based indexing which means writing 3 will select 4th

Comment: Not with `"tr"` in selector. There is only one match in whole page

Answer (score 1):

From the row : use `find(classSelector)` or `eq(index)` of the children

```
$('#<%= gvView.ClientID %> input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
    var signValue =  $(this).closest('tr').children('td').eq(3).text();
    // or
    var signValue =  $(this).closest('tr').find('.cellClassName').text(); 

});
```