# jQuery not selecting all div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I run this code only the first div is selected and only the first second p tag("which contain "Greetings") is empty, but leaves the other second p tags in the other two divs unaffected. I want all three divs to be affected so that all the second p tags("which contain "Greetings") are empty.

```js
var e = $('div').children();
e.eq(1).empty();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>jQuery Effects</title>
    <style media="screen">
      div{
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: teal;
        float: left;
        margin: 20px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Click Me</button>
    <div>
      <p>Hello</p>
      <p>Greetings</p>
      <p>Bye</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Hello</p>
      <p>Greetings</p>
      <p>Bye</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Hello</p>
      <p>Greetings</p>
      <p>Bye</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The first line already selects all `<div>`s and all their children. `.eq`, however, doesn’t yield the second child of every `<div>`, just the second item in the list of all children. You could try just `$('div > p:nth-child(2)').empty();` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to select n-th td of a tr using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229145/how-to-select-n-th-td-of-a-tr-using-jquery)

Comment: @Xufox Thanks for explaining why it wasn't working rather than just providing me the solution otherwise I would have been still been confused. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is not with the below code

```
var e = $('div').children();
```

It is selecting all three divs and there children, so when you do  console.log(e) you will get all 9 p tags (3 for each div). The problem is with

```
e.eq(1)
```

When you do this you are only selecting the second p tag out of all nine.
Instead of that try using

```
p:nth-of-type(2)
```

selector in the children like this. Which will only select the 2nd p tags from all the divs.

```js
var e = $('div').children('p:nth-of-type(2)');
e.empty();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>jQuery Effects</title>
    <style media="screen">
      div{
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: teal;
        float: left;
        margin: 20px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Click Me</button>
    <div>
      <p>Hello</p>
      <p>Greetings</p>
      <p>Bye</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Hello</p>
      <p>Greetings</p>
      <p>Bye</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Hello</p>
      <p>Greetings</p>
      <p>Bye</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

the comment of @Xufox is a very good short solution ( using `$('div > p:nth-child(2)').empty();` link to `nth` in the bottom ) but if you want more detailed one :

to select the 2nd `p` of each `div` and empty it,

you can loop through the `div`s and use `nth` to select the 2nd `p`

try this :

```
$('div').each(function(ndx,elem){
    $(elem).children('p:nth(1)').empty();
});
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5xt0makw/9/

> The :nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth
>   child, regardless of type, of its parent.

nth selector : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

> the `.each` function can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and
>   arrays.

jQuery `.each` : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

i hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is not it better to do a "each" and get all the values to better work them?
E.g.:

```
$("div").each((a, b) => {
  console.log(a, b);
});
```